# SQL Check If Data in Column A Exists in Column B

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have an Employee Table

`EmployeeID` | `Name` | `EmployeeEmail` | `ManagerEmail`

---

Every `ManagerEmail` should belong to a Manager-Level Employee, being their primary email as `EmployeeEmail`.

I would like to check if there are any `ManagerEmail` that does not belong to any  Employee.

---

The DBMS that I am using is Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2014.

May I know how can I accomplish that?

Thank you.

Comment: What you tried so far?

Comment: Give some sample code.

Comment: Tag the only DBMS which you are really using.

Comment: SELECT * FROM Employee
WHERE ManagerEmail NOT IN (SELECT Email FROM Employee)

Comment: @gymcode, what property in the employee table can be used to identify if an employee is of "Manager-Level". I am trying to understand how to flag this conditon  "Every ManagerEmail should belong to a Manager-Level Employee"

Comment: My apologies for the confusion. What I was trying to say was for every `ManagerEmail`, it should belong to an Employee. I am trying to check if any `ManagerEmail` does not belong to anyone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seems want :

```
select e.*
from Employee e
where e.ManagerEmail is not null and
      not exists (select 1 
                  from Employee e1 
                  where e1.EmployeeEmail = e.ManagerEmail
                 );
```

EDIT: Added the additional `WHERE` clause based on the OP's comment.

Comment: `not exists` is much preferable to `not in` with a subquery (the latter will return no rows if any `employeeEmail`s are `NULL`).

Comment: After I ran the command, I retrieved records from users that have an existing `EmployeeEmail`, but a NULL `ManagerEmail`

Comment: My intention is to find out if any `ManagerEmail` does not belong to an employee's `EmployeeEmail`

Comment: @gymcode, try it now, with the additional `where` clause.

Answer (score 0):

As this is a very general question, the answer is equally general. Use one of these methods:

- NOT IN
- NOT EXISTS
- EXCEPT
- an anti join

As it seems that none of these came to mind, you may want to study all of them. You should at least learn how to apply the first three, in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following query-:

```
select ManagerEmail from YourTableName 
where ManagerEmail not in (select EmployeeEmail from YourTableName)
```

SQL Server